# Use neighbors wifi behind my own firewall

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

My neighbor is letting me use his wifi.

But I do not want my devices (phone, laptop) visible on his subnet. E. G. I never want my actual devices (laptop and phones) to ever attach to his wifi ap.

Can I set up a wifi to wifi bridge, on my side, so my devices are protected?

To be clear, I do NOT mean bridging in the sense of the OSI stack. I mean a setup like this:

MyWifiSID - -(NAT)-- > MyWifiAP - - > NeighborWifiAP - - (NAT) --> Public

Note, without making any tweaks on his side.

If so, how?

Would a nuc approach like this work? https://www.reddit.com/r/intelnuc/comments/bt5sxb/making_a_wireless_ap_and_router_with_intel_nuc/

Comment: Yes, you can setup a wifi to wifi bridge on some kind of device, and put in firewall rules. Note that this single device will be visible to your neighbour. Also note this device needs WLAN hardware capable of using a WLAN client interface and WLAN access point (AP) interface at the same time. Which device were you planning to use for this? A cheap homerouter where you can install OpenWRT etc.would be a good choice.

Comment: @dirkt can I use an Intel nuc?

Comment: In principle, yes, e.g. [this NUC](https://www.linuxmintusers.de/index.php?topic=20675.0) (Intel Wireless-AC 7260) supports both AP and `managed` (client) at the same time, but only on the same channel (look at `valid interface combinations`). There are x86 builds of OpenWRT, though I don't know if anyone has tried to install it on an Intel NUC. Restriction to the same channel means your bandwidth over WLAN will be half the maximum. Which is not a problem if it's still larger than your neighbour's ISP's bandwidth.

Answer (score -1):

(I assume you are on Windows 10.)

If you don't want your computer to be discoverable on the neighbor's network,
you need to 
[Define the network as Public](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4043043/windows-10-make-network-public-private):

1. On the right side of the taskbar, select the Wi-Fi network  icon
2. Under the name of the Wi-Fi network that you’re connected to, select *Properties*
3. Under Network profile, select *Public*.

Another solution that applies both to computers and smart phones, is to
use a VPN to communicate to the Internet. This way, the owner of the
WiFi router cannot see anything except the fact that your devices are
connected to his router. Since he cannot join your VPN network,
he cannot access your computer or smart phones.

Comment: Harry, the question you answered is not the one I ask.

Comment: Please explain, or add more detail in the post, since it seems to me that this is indeed the answer.

Comment: OP updated. Thanks!

Comment: This answer is updated to include other devices than the Windows computer.

Comment: Harry, thanks for the elaboration. I think you are still answering a question other than the one posted, which is looking for a way to bridge wifi networks.

Comment: Is bridging the wifi more important than having your devices protected? Bridging will make the two houses into one network.

Comment: Harry, OP enhanced further for clarity RE bridging.